# Trying to add values to existing dataframe by specific ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset

Basically i calculated the fantasy points for each player for each specific game ID, and now i have another dataframe that has 10 columns that are empty and need to add the fantasy points for each column and add it for the current game id.

```
k = game_details_sorted['GAME_ID'].unique()

for x in k:
    lis = game_details_sorted.loc[game_details_sorted['GAME_ID'] == x]
    abb = lis['TEAM_ABBREVIATION'].unique()

    y = game_details_sorted[(game_details_sorted['GAME_ID'] == x) & (
        game_details_sorted['TEAM_ABBREVIATION'] == abb[0])]
    y3 = game_details_sorted[(game_details_sorted['GAME_ID'] == x) & (
        game_details_sorted['TEAM_ABBREVIATION'] == abb[1])]
    z = y['FP'].iloc[0:5].to_numpy()
    z3 = y3['FP'].iloc[0:5].to_numpy()
    # j = z['FP'].to_numpy()
    # f3 = z3['FP'].to_numpy()

    #print(games.loc[games['GAME_ID'] == x])
    selected_features = ['player1_home', 'player2_home', 'player3_home', 'player4_home',
                         'player5_home']
    selected_features_away = ['player1_away', 'player2_away', 'player3_away', 'player4_away',
                              'player5_away']
    z2 =games.loc[games['GAME_ID'] == x]
    games[selected_features] = z
    games[selected_features_away] = z3
```

I have tried this but every game id gets entered with same data. [image]
this is the data, so basically the best 5 fantasy points for each team, need to be added to the dataframe on top.

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up doing this and it worked but it takes a few minutes to complete.

```
for x in k:
    gg = []
    # lis = game_details_sorted.loc[game_details_sorted['GAME_ID'] == x]
    yy = games.loc[games['GAME_ID'] == x]['HOME_TEAM_ID'].values[0]
    print(yy)
    ya = games.loc[games['GAME_ID'] == x]['VISITOR_TEAM_ID'].values[0]
    print(ya)
    gg.append(yy)
    gg.append(ya)
    #abb = set(lis['TEAM_ABBREVIATION'])
    y = game_details_sorted.loc[(game_details_sorted['GAME_ID'] == x) & (
        game_details_sorted['TEAM_ABBREVIATION'] == gg[0])]['FP'].iloc[0:5].to_numpy()
    print(y)
    y3 = game_details_sorted.loc[(game_details_sorted['GAME_ID'] == x) & (
        game_details_sorted['TEAM_ABBREVIATION'] == gg[1])]['FP'].iloc[0:5].to_numpy()
    print(y3)
    # z = y['FP'].iloc[0:5].to_numpy()
    # z3 = y3['FP'].iloc[0:5].to_numpy()

    zzz = games.loc[games['GAME_ID'] == x].index
    selected_features = ['player1_home', 'player2_home', 'player3_home', 'player4_home',
                         'player5_home']
    selected_features_away = ['player1_away', 'player2_away', 'player3_away', 'player4_away',
                              'player5_away']

    # z2 =games.loc[games['GAME_ID'] == x]
    games.loc[zzz, selected_features] = y
    games.loc[zzz, selected_features_away] = y3

    print(games.reset_index(drop=True))

games.to_csv('checkData.csv')
```

Comment: if anyone can think of a way of making it faster please let me know